# What's the difference between naive and memory B cells?

Tags: immunology, cell

I understand that when naive B cells are exposed to antigens, they become memory B cells, but what is the functional difference between the two? I've looked at the quite a few article on B cells, but none of them stated the difference clearly enough for me to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that memory B cells start an immune reaction much more effective and faster than naive B cells. The reaction is also specific towards the antigen.

The memory B cell has a specific membrane receptor for an antigen. It produces specific antibodies only when exposed to the antigen.

References:

- Tangye SG, Avery DT, Deenick EK, Hodgkin PD. [Intrinsic differences in the proliferation of naive and memory human B cells as a mechanism for enhanced secondary immune responses.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12517929) J. Immunol. 2003 Jan 15;170(2):686-94. PubMed PMID: 12517929.
- Wikipedia contributors, "B cell," Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=B_cell&oldid=612990219 (accessed June 26, 2014).

Answer (score 0):

Naive B cells have not yet been trained by the immune system to recognize specific antigens -therefore the term "naive". Prior to antigen exposure, they must be trained in the bone marrow to recognize certain antigens.

Memory B cells, on the other hand, are formed after antigen exposure and clonal selection. As stated above, they have specific receptors for antigens and can produce antibodies.

Comment: They are actually not trained in the bone marrow, but in germinal centers in the lymphatic tissues.